# android: start java script on webpage and receiving result

Tags: javascript, android

I want to run js on webpage from my android app. For example, searching in google or other searches. Usually there is a button "Search", which runs javascript function. This function returns search results which are rendered by browser. I want to get these results in my app.

I'm trying to do it with Jsoup, but it gives me empty page without js results

Comment: You should look at using an API, rather than trying to second-guess what a web page does and try and use it.  Is it specifically a Google search you want to do?

Comment: nope, i want to know how it can be achieved in general, google is an example

Comment: You want to be able to run "the javascript" on any web page and get the results in your app?

Comment: i wan to be able run the javascript from the page which has it, not on any webpage obviously

Comment: What page? what is the script file called, or is it embedded in the page?  What does the script do?  What function does it run? What does the function return?  How does it store the data it accesses?  Please supply a [MCVE] and we can help fix your problem :)

Comment: okay) the webpage url is https://www.amoyshare.com/free-mp3-finder/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162817/discussion-between-borune-and-archer).

Comment: You need to supply a [MCVE] before anyone can help you.  We can go into chat if you like, but you probably won't want to pay my hourly rate :)